# cannot create temp dir(Cloud based gallery)

Tags: android, caching, internal-storage

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 9949
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.backup.component.D2dTransportService: kdb: Cannot create temp dir
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: kdb: Cannot create temp dir
        at kda.b(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):11)
        at kda.a(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):4)
        at kcy.a(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):2)
        at kcy.(Unknown Source:5)
        at kfw.(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.d2d.component.D2dTransportChimeraService.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):1)
        at dge.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):1)
        at nqd.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms@12862026@12.8.62 (040700-199405334):3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide more info on efforts you made and code.